# Awk replace after loop

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I want to override the child_value with the parent_value using awk. The solution must be generic applicable for larger data sources. The parent-record is defined by $1==$2.

This is my input file (format: ID;PARENT_ID;VALUE):

```
10;20;child_value
20;20;parent_value
```

This is the result I want:

```
10;20;parent_value
20;20;parent_value
```

This is my current approach:

```
  awk -F\;
        BEGIN {
            OFS = FS
        }
        {
            if ($1 == $2) {
                mapping[$1] = $3
            }
            all[$1]=$0
        } 
        END {
            for (i in all) {
              if (i[$3] == 'child_value') {
                 i[$3] = mapping[i]
              }
              print i
            }
        }
    ' file.in
```

Needless to say, that it doesn't work like that ;-) Anyone can help?

Comment: Is `child_value` is constant or dynamic value ? Will it have more than one child-parent values ? If so, How to match parent and corresponding child ?

Comment: Can a child have a child (ie. `5;10;typical_teen_value`)? Does it get `parent_value` or `child_value`?

Comment: @JamesBrown there is no recursion

Comment: @sat actually child_value will be constantly an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for multiple parent/child pairs perhaps on non-consecutive lines...

```
$ awk -F\; -v OFS=\; 'NR==FNR {if($1==$2) a[$2]=$3; next} 
                      $1!=$2  {$3=a[$2]}1' file{,}

10;20;parent_value
20;20;parent_value
```

assumes the second field is the parent id.

Comment: This solutions works perfectly. Many thanks @karakfa!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your data is sorted in descnding order (you could use `sort` if not sorted at all or `rev` if data is sorted in ascending order) before processing, it's enough to hash the first entry of each key in `$2` and use the value on the first match for the following records with the same key in `$2`:

```
$ sort -t\; -k2nr -k1nr bar | \ 
awk '
BEGIN{ 
    FS=OFS=";"
}
{
    if($2 in a)      # if $2 in hash a, use it
        $3=a[$2]     
    else             # else add it
        a[$2]=$3
    if(p!=$2)        # delete previous entries from wasting memory
        delete a[p]
    p=$2             # p is for previous on next round
}1'
20;20;parent_value
10;20;parent_value
```